# Angular 8 - Overriding array element

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to overwrite an element of the array with a new element.
When the list is an element when inserting a new one by parameter, the element that is inside the array must be overwritten

My filled list:
1, Honda, 2020
2, Audi, 2020

Desired list after inserting the new model via parameter
1, Mustang, 2021

My method that should do that.

```
public overwriteModel(model: string) {
  models.push(new Model(1, model, 2021));
}
```

But when I push it, I’m adding a new element to the array and it was supposed to be overwritten. In other words, delete all the elements of the array and insert what I passed as a parameter

Comment: So whenever a new element is added, it should delete all other elements and then only add the new element?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript for that. Find the index for item you want to replace and then insert your new element into the array at that index.

```
const i = models.findIndex(x => x.name == “Honda...


models[i] = new Model(1, model, 2021);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. If the model already exists in the array it will be overridden. If it does not exist, it will be added in array.

```js
let models = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Honda', year: 2020},
  {id: 2, name: 'Audi', year: 2020},
  {id: 3, name: 'Mustang', year: 2020},
]

function overwriteModel(model: string) {
  let index = models.findIndex((m)=> m.name === model);
  if(index !== -1){
     models[index] = {id: 1, name: model, year: 2021 }
  } else {
     models.push( {id: 1, name: model, year: 2021 } );
  }
}

console.log('Initial Models: ', models);
overwriteModel('Mustang');
console.log('Models After Override: ', models);
```

Comment: In this case and to delete all records and leave only the new element in the list